# SSRS Text box height while exporting to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using text boxes above my SSRS graphs to show the legend instead of the normal legens. This looks better and consumes less space in my graphs. When I preview the SSRS report, it looks great in visual studio and report manager. When I export the report, the height of the textboxes is doubled. Does anybody now how to fix this? I tried a rectangle around but no lock.

Comment: Maybe check that on all the tables/textboxes involved, that the **CanGrow** property is set to *False*?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I put everything in a rectangle and set all properties to CanGrowth = False. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I figured it would probably help, but couldn't be sure, so that's why I left the comment. I will add as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, SSRS Excel exports do have a tendency to stretch out rows unpredictably.

In general, the best solution is to make sure that any individual textboxes or textboxes within a Tablix have their **CanGrow** property set to *False*. Make sure that all textboxes in a table are set up this way or it might not work.